# Webpack wont resolve asset alias in js-files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've created a webpack config, where I have 'assets', 'styles', 'scripts' and 'twig.
Because my 'build' layout is different from the 'dev' enviroment, I've created some aliases to resolve.

### Problem

When running webpack (dev-mode & prod-mode), it almost seems to work perfectly. Except for some aliases:

- Asset alias in my canvas.js

  ```
  app.loader.add('test', 'ImageFiles/test.png').load((loader, resources) => {

  // This creates a texture from a 'bunny.png' image
  const test = new Sprite(resources.test.texture);

  // Setup the position of the bunny
  test.x = app.renderer.width / 2;
  test.y = app.renderer.height / 2;

  // Rotate around the center
  test.anchor.x = 0.5;
  test.anchor.y = 0.5;

  // Add the bunny to the scene we are building
  app.stage.addChild(test);

  // Listen for frame updates
  app.ticker.add(() => {
    // each frame we spin the bunny around a bit
    test.rotation += 0.01;
  });
  });
  ```
- Favicon asset in my layout.twig

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>{{ siteTitle }}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{{ siteDescription }}">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="FaviconFiles/favicon.ico">
  ```

### My structure

```
- src
  - favicon
      - favicon.ico
  - fonts
    - poppins-v9-latin-500.ttf
    - (some more)
  - images
    - test.png
  - partials
    - layout.twig
  - scripts
    - index.js
    - canvas.js
  - styles
    - sass
      - fonts.scss
    - style.scss
  - index.twig
- webpack
  - webpack.common.js
  - webpack.config.dev.js
  - webpack.config.prod.js
- node_modules
- package.json
- .htaccess
- .babelrc
```

### My Webpack config

**webpack.common.js**

```
const Path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/scripts/index.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: Path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: false,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.twig'),
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
      {
        test: /\.twig$/,
        use: [
          'raw-loader',
          'twig-html-loader'
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**webpack.config.dev.js**

```
const Path = require('path');
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

// Let us use Node JS
const fs = require('fs');

// Get all pages in /src by filtering .twig
const pages = fs.readdirSync(Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/')).
  filter(fileName => fileName.endsWith('.twig') && fileName !== 'index.twig');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].chunk.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    }),
    ...pages.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: Path.resolve(__dirname, ('../src' + page)),
      filename: page.replace('.twig', ''),
    })),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      FaviconFiles: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/favicon'),
      ScriptFiles: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/scripts'),
      StyleFiles: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles'),
      ImageFiles: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/images'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
          emitWarning: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap=true'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
const Path = require('path');
const Glob = require('glob');
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const PurgecssPlugin = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

// Let us use Node JS
const fs = require('fs');

// Get all pages in /src by filtering .twig
const pages = fs.readdirSync(Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/')).
  filter(fileName => fileName.endsWith('.twig') && fileName !== 'index.twig');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  stats: 'errors-only',
  bail: true,
  output: {
    filename: 'js/bundle-[hash]-[id].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/bundle-[hash]-[id].chunk.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'FaviconFiles': Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/favicon'),
      'ScriptFiles': Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/scripts'),
      'StyleFiles': Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles'),
      'ImageFiles': Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/images'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/images'), to: 'images',
        },
        {
          from: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../.htaccess'),
        },
        {
          from: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/fonts'), to: 'fonts',
        },
        {
          from: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/favicon'), to: 'favicon',
        },
      ],
    }),
    ...pages.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: page.replace('twig', 'html'),
      template: Path.resolve(__dirname, ('../src/' + page)),
    })),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles/bundle-[hash].css',
    }),
    new PurgecssPlugin({
      whitelistPatterns: [/bullet$/, /bullet-active$/, /collapse$/],
      whitelist: ['collapsing'],
      paths: Glob.sync(`${Path.join(__dirname, '../src')}/**/*`,
        {nodir: true}),
    }),
  ],
});
```

When building my website, I want the following structure:

```
- dist
  - favicon
  - fonts
  - images
  - js
  - styles
  - index.html
  - .htaccess
```

Why doesn't it recognize these aliases? It does not give me any errors unfortunately, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is your problem images disappeared in your build dir?

Comment: The images are there, but the alias isn't replaced by to right path.
For instance; I get a 'GET http://localhost:8080/ImageFiles/test.png 404 (Not Found)'. It doesn't replace the 'ImageFiles' alias with the right path.

Comment: It looks like you have configured wrongly by using both `file-loader` + copy plugin. I think you just simply use file loader only

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've deleted the 'CopyWebpackPlugin' section, but that fixes not my problem unfortunately.
I also face the problem when running webpack dev-mode. No copy plugin is used there.

Comment: You might have to use `import` (if you're writing in esm style) or `require` keyword to require your image in your script `import yourImageUrl from "Images/..."`. One more thing, if you want to store your images in dir `images` in build dir, you have to configure `file-loader` where to store

Comment: Thanks! That worked.
I do still have the same issue with the favicon 'FaviconFiles/favicon.ico' in my layout.twig. A import isn't a option there. Any ideas?

Comment: Just simply import your your favicon in your entry file `import "path/to/favicon"`

Comment: Or you can use this plugin instead https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin, it would work with html plugin

Comment: I tried that, and the image is rendered! But the href '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="FaviconFiles/favicon.ico">' isn't changed. It won't seems to connect the import favicon.ico with the one in layout.twig. Is this maybe because of the 'twig-html-loader'?

Comment: Since `webpack` doesn't populate anything to your template which means you have to use the correct import related to your build assets (import above just make sure favicon image getting bundled). You can use either above plugin I sent or refine your template + copy plugin to copy your favicon to image dir (won't use import favicon in this case)